# Grabbing JSON and mapping it to an object

Tags: json, angular, rxjs, ngrx, angular-httpclient

I was wondering how I could get JSON data from a link that I have hosted online. I'm trying to get the lat and lng coordinates in a service and then use them in my component.

**The JSON format is similar to:**

`"devices"{[
   "lat": 1234567
   "lon": 1234567
]}`

**I'm trying to map the JSON objects like this:**

```
 private busFeed = 'azure.com/file.json';

  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {}


   getFirstDevice() {
     return this._http.get(this.busFeed).pipe(
      map(data => data),
      tap(data => console.log('Device Info: ' + JSON.stringify(data)))
     );
   }
```

**And my TransportComponent is like this:**

```
this._transportFeed.getFirstDevice()
  .subscribe(transportFeed => {
    this.devices = transportFeed;
  });
```

The issue I'm facing is that this is grabbing all the information from the JSON document when I only want the latitude and longitude coordinates. I wish to display both in the .ts file and not in the .html file as I want to plot these coordinates in a map marker in a map.

Comment: That is not valid JSON. Can you recheck your JSON format? See this for more information on valid JSON formats: https://developers.squarespace.com/what-is-json

Answer (score 0):

```
this._transportFeed.getFirstDevice()
   .subscribe(transportFeed => {
      this.devices = transportFeed.map(obj => ({
          lat: transportFeed.lat,
          lon: transportFeed.lon
     })
  });
```

or

```
getFirstDevice() {
 return this._http.get(this.busFeed).pipe(
  map(data => ({ lat: data.lat, lon: data.lon})),
  tap(data => console.log('Device Info: ' + 
  JSON.stringify(data)))
 );
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! The error I'm receiving when I try both of these is: Property 'lat' does not exist on type 'Object', Property 'lon' does not exist on type 'Object'.

Comment: what type is this.devices? Try to chsnge it to 'any'

Comment: I changed it to this.devices = {
          lat: transportFeed[0].lat,
          lon: transportFeed[0].lon
        }; and now I've an error of Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined